# Android embedded Felix missing requirement osgi.ee

Tags: java, android, eclipse, osgi, apache-felix

I'm trying to convince an embedded Apache Felix on Android to start an external bundle.
So far I have managed to embed the felix.jar into its own APK and run it as an activity. Within this activity I'm able to install outside bundles from jar files. Unfortunately whenever I try to move on and start one of these bundles I get the following error:

Encountered exception when starting bundle:

```
Unresolved constraint in bundle com.example.hellofelix [1]:        
Unable to resolve 1.0:             
missing requirement [1.0] osgi.ee;                           
(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7.0))
```

As `com.example.hellofelix` is the package name for my test application this suggests that my app is missing the osgi.ee package required by the constraint of `JavaSE 1.7.0.`

How exactly do I solve this problem?
Do I have to specify en extra export in my app, import something or just add another bundle?

My bundle's code:

Activator:

```
package com.example.dictionary;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

import com.example.dictionary.service.DictionaryBundle;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

  public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    props.put("Language", "de-en");
    context.registerService(DictionaryBundle.class.getName(), new DictionaryBundleImpl(), props);
  }

  public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    // NOTE: The service is automatically unregistered.
  }

}
```

Interface:

```
package com.example.dictionary.service;

public interface DictionaryBundle {

    public String translate(String wordToTranslate);

}
```

Implementation:

```
package com.example.dictionary;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import com.example.dictionary.service.DictionaryBundle;

public class DictionaryBundleImpl implements DictionaryBundle {

    private Hashtable<String, String> dictionary;

    public DictionaryBundleImpl() {
        dictionary = new Hashtable<>();

        dictionary.put("ente", "duck");
        dictionary.put("hund", "dog");
        dictionary.put("kuh", "cow");
        dictionary.put("katze", "cat");
        dictionary.put("maus", "mouse");
    }

    public String translate(String wordToTranslate) {
        return dictionary.get(wordToTranslate);
    }

}
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.hellofelix
Export-Package: com.example.dictionary.service
Bundle-Name: TestBundle
Bundle-Version: 1.4.2.qualifier
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Activator: com.example.dictionary.Activator
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-Vendor: None
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The bundle's manifest says that it requires JavaSE 1.7. And your runtime does not supply that JRE. So it fails to resolve as it should.

You can either change the bundle to target a different osgi.ee (the one in Android) or you can tell Felix to lie and claim that the osgi.ee is JavaSE 1.7.

That is, either change the requirement in the bundle or the capability provided by the framework.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Could you please elaborate a little bit on your suggestion. I'm new to Android and may not fully understand the respective differences in Java requirements. Currently I'm running Android Kitkat 4.4.4 with ART and expected it to be in general 1,7 compliant. So what exactly would I need to do to change the bundle's requirement to Android's osgi.ee or add the mssing capability to the felix framework?